# Prevent auto validation

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery and I seem to have come across a annoying problem.

How do I make the validation work only when a person hits submit?

Would I have to say -- if submit == true run function ?

```
  <script>

  $('#add_film').submit(function (e) {

var error = false;

// No value for movie_title
if ($('#movie_title').val() == "") {
    alert("No Film");
    error = true;
}

// No Value for actor
if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
    alert("No actor");
    error = true;
}

// No value for rating
if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
    alert("No Rating");
    error = true;
}

//No value for review
if ($('#review').val() == "") {
    alert("No review");
    error = true;
}

// Focus on first form field.
$("input:text:visible:first").focus();

if (error) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

});

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove it from .ready(), add it to onclick, on submit button. You might want to keep some of it on the .ready()... like focus on first element part.

Answer (score 1):

Move your code to click event of your button like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").on('click',function(){
            // No value for movie_title
        if ($('#movie_title').val() == "" ) {
            alert ("No Film");
        }

        // No Value for actor
        if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
            alert ("No actor");
        }

        // No value for rating
        if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
            alert ("No Rating");
        }

        //No value for review
        if ($('#review').val() == "") {
            alert ("No review");
        }
});
    // Focus on first form field.
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should validate your form on form `submit` event:

```
$('#add_film').submit(function (e) {

    var error = false;

    // No value for movie_title
    if ($('#movie_title').val() == "") {
        alert("No Film");
        error = true;
    }

    // No Value for actor
    if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
        alert("No actor");
        error = true;
    }

    // No value for rating
    if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
        alert("No Rating");
        error = true;
    }

    //No value for review
    if ($('#review').val() == "") {
        alert("No review");
        error = true;
    }

    // Focus on first form field.
    $("input:text:visible:first").focus();

    if (error) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fnEa/

By the way, do not be tempted to bind validation to click event *on the button*, this is incorrect. Form elements have **submit** event for this purpose. Also make sure you prevent default behavior of the form in case of errors.

Comment: The OP might want to focus on the first input element on document ready itself. In that case `$("input:text:visible:first").focus();` should be inside document ready only.

Answer (score 0):

Alert errors, flag if any, if there is flag - prevent submission form:

```
$('#add_film').submit(function(e) {

        var err=0;

        // No value for movie_title
        if ($('#movie_title').val() == "" ) {
            alert ("No Film");
            err = 1;
        }
        // No Value for actor
        if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
            alert ("No actor");
            err = 1;
        }
        // No value for rating
        if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
            alert ("No Rating");
            err = 1;
        }
        //No value for review
        if ($('#review').val() == "") {
            alert ("No review");
            err = 1;
        }
    // Focus on first form field.
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();

        if(err == 1){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Comment: It's not very good idea, because you will get into infinite validation loop.

Comment: @dfsq no, not really. it's another call of submit and there is no validation rules?

Comment: @dfsq anyway, I've amended it - no problem